# ASP.NET: Should connection be closed right after adapter has filled the dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, adapter

I am using a GridView and wonder if it's better for me to close the connection IMMEDIATELY after the

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

statement or I should wait until I've done:

```
GridView.DataSource = ds;
GridView.DataBind();
```

I assume once the dataset has been filled, I no longer need the connection. Am I wrong?

Comment: who asked you to open a connection. there is no need to do open `SqlConnection` if adapter is `SqlDataAdapter` and ds is `DataSet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `adapter.Fill(ds);` the data is loaded into memory and you can close the connection immediately after this statement. After, when you set ds as DataSource to the gridview, it will bind the data from memory.

Have a look into this article for understanding [Working with Disconnected Data - The DataSet and SqlDataAdapter](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson05.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

After call to `Fill()`, you can safely close the connection. Offtopic: make it a practice using [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) block when dealing with `IDisposable` (like `SqlConnection`) entities so, in this case, you wouldn't have to manually call `Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataAdapter` doesn't need `connection` after filling data into `DataSet`, but if you are doing any `data manipulation` after that line you will need to open it again, what i do is i write all such statements in [`finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke0zf0f5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) block.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to open the `SqlConnection` at all as `DataSet` has a disconnected architecture.

> The DataSet is the main data storage
>   tool in the ADO.NET disconnected
>   architecture. Unlike the DataReader,
>   the DataSet is not connected directly
>   to a database through a Connection
>   object when you populate it. Instead,
>   to fill a DataSet from a database you
>   first create a DataAdapter object
>   (such as a SqlDataAdapter) for the
>   provider and associate it with a
>   SqlConnection object. Then the
>   SqlDataAdapter can broker the data
>   retrieval for the DataSet by issuing a
>   SqlCommand against the database
>   through the SqlConnection, retrieving
>   the data, and filling the DataSet

A very basic example of usage will be

```
string sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Products";
string sConnString = 
    "Server=(local);Database=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlDataAdapter oDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
using(SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection(sConnString))
{
    SqlCommand oSelCmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oCn);
    oSelCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    oDa.SelectCommand = oSelCmd;
    oDa.Fill(oDs, "Products");
}
```

Source: [Contrasting the ADO.NET DataReader and DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx)

Comment: -1: The need to "not" open or close the SQL Connection has **nothing** to do with it being "disconnected". To get data from a database (MSSQL/Oracle/...) a connection must be established. However, an SQL DataAdapter controls the connection and it (the Adapter) handles the open & close within the _Fill_ method.

Comment: @ Cos Callis: i would call that plain ignorance. i stick to the notion that OP does not have to do `conn.Close()` at all since he did not do a `conn.open()`

Comment: @Naveen, that is not what you said.. you said the OP does not have to `conn.Close()` **BECAUSE** a `DataSet is disconnected`. That is fostering ignorance. The OP does not have to do `conn.Close()` **BECAUSE** the adapter handles that.

Comment: @ Cos Callis: I said this. There is no need to open the SqlConnection at all as DataSet has a disconnected architecture. Please don't put words to my mouth. you can check my answer. i haven't edited anything at all.

Comment: @Naveen, in your opening remark the word "AS" (`There is no need to open the SqlConnection at all as DataSet has a disconnected architecture.` means "Because", this is not putting words in your mouth. You attribute that the reason the connection does not to be closed has something to do with the idea that a DataSet is "disconnected". This is false: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx (first paragraph under remarks). To get to the data you must have a connection. It is good for the OP (and you) to understand there is connection, it is opened and it is closed _by the adapter_!

Comment: the remark came after your downvote right? in my answer i have explicitly stated that since there is no need of a conn.Open there shouldn't be a connection.close. and having a connection and keeping it open are very different things

Comment: I read your response, I knew it to be **misleading**, I voted it down and then took the time to explain it. I knew the explanation before I voted it down.